# How to specify virtual Address for pl011 uart in linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded

I am a beginner in kernel porting. I am trying to port Linux kernel (version- 4.9.22) on Custom SoC (cpu = arm1176jzfs based) for custom evaluation Board. I am having ARM Prime cell pl011 UART in my SoC. And it is physically mapped to `0x5800_1000` address. While i am trying to use it as Debug UART, kernel is asking for its virtual Address. How should i configure this option.

i.e:

```
-> Kernel low-level debugging functions
    -> kernel low-level debugging port (Kernel low-level debugging on via ARM Ltd PL01x Primecell UART)
(0x58001000) Physical base address of debug UART
(??) Virtual base address of debug UART
```

Thanks,
Vivek T.

Comment: Virtual address of that is just a mapping of physical one using set of rules (usually really simple, like bit shifts and bit masks). You need to figure out first *why* driver configuration asks this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a debugger, then you can certainly debug why your kernel is not booting up.

You can watch this steps:

-In Kernel configuration, enable CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO (Kernel Hacking -> Compile-time checks and compiler options)

-Compile the kernel

-From the debugger software, load the symbols from the elf. The command varies from one debugger to another

-Find symbol "log_buf", and chose option to "Display memory as dump"

So I think the kernel logs stored in the buffer. Maybe it can help you :)

Answer (score -1):

Standard UART addresses are:

Standard port addresses are:

COM1 0x3F8 (1016)
 COM2 0x2F8 (760)
 COM3 0x3E8 (1000)
 COM4 0x2E8 (744)

Additional port addresses are:

COM5 0x3E0 (992)
 COM6 0x2E0 (736)
 COM7 0x338 (824)
 COM8 0x238 (568)